# MobileFirst 7.0 Server stuck "Deploying" when trying to deploy a .wlapp file to Tomcat

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-console

While after finishing installing and configuring successfully the MobileFirst 7.0 Server, I'm getting the issue that the MF server is stucking in "Deploying" when I try to `Deploy Application` `=>` `Selecting a MF studio /bin folder .wlapp file`.

[image]

And here are some log messages from Tomcat log files:

```
10614  WorklightManagementPU-mysql  INFO   [pool-2-thread-1] openjpa.Runtime - Though you are using optimistic transactions, OpenJPA is now beginning a datastore transaction because you have requested a lock on some data.
10646  WorklightManagementPU-mysql  INFO   [pool-2-thread-1] openjpa.Runtime - Though you are using optimistic transactions, OpenJPA is now beginning a datastore transaction because you have requested a lock on some data.
10682  WorklightManagementPU-mysql  INFO   [pool-2-thread-1] openjpa.Runtime - Though you are using optimistic transactions, OpenJPA is now beginning a datastore transaction because you have requested a lock on some data.

Jun 03, 2015 2:03:32 PM com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.ApplicationDeploymentTransaction beforeAll
SEVERE: Failed to generate download links to transfer data during the deployment of applications. See the next exception in the log. Switch to direct data transfer via JMX. This is not fatal but it requires larger memory than the data transfer with download links.
Jun 03, 2015 2:03:32 PM com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.BaseTransaction internalRun
SEVERE: BaseTransaction.internalRun() Exception
<openjpa-1.2.2-r422266:898935 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Object "com.ibm.worklight.dataaccess.jpa.entity.ProjectEntity-com.ibm.worklight.dataaccess.jpa.entity.ProjectEntity-1" is not managed by this context.
FailedObject: com.ibm.worklight.dataaccess.jpa.entity.ProjectEntity-com.ibm.worklight.dataaccess.jpa.entity.ProjectEntity-1
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.processArgument(EntityManagerImpl.java:1216)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.processArgument(BrokerImpl.java:2149)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.gatherCascadeRefresh(BrokerImpl.java:2816)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.refresh(BrokerImpl.java:2793)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBroker.refresh(DelegatingBroker.java:1078)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.refresh(EntityManagerImpl.java:688)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.BaseTransaction.setNewProjectTransactionID(BaseTransaction.java:643)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.BaseTransaction.internalRun(BaseTransaction.java:336)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.BaseTransaction$1.run(BaseTransaction.java:235)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Jun 03, 2015 2:03:32 PM com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.BaseTransaction$1 run
SEVERE: internalRun() Exception
<openjpa-1.2.2-r422266:898935 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Object "com.ibm.worklight.dataaccess.jpa.entity.ProjectEntity-com.ibm.worklight.dataaccess.jpa.entity.ProjectEntity-1" is not managed by this context.
FailedObject: com.ibm.worklight.dataaccess.jpa.entity.ProjectEntity-com.ibm.worklight.dataaccess.jpa.entity.ProjectEntity-1
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.processArgument(EntityManagerImpl.java:1216)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.processArgument(BrokerImpl.java:2149)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.gatherCascadeRefresh(BrokerImpl.java:2816)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.refresh(BrokerImpl.java:2793)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBroker.refresh(DelegatingBroker.java:1078)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.refresh(EntityManagerImpl.java:688)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.BaseTransaction.setNewProjectTransactionID(BaseTransaction.java:643)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.BaseTransaction.internalRun(BaseTransaction.java:336)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.BaseTransaction$1.run(BaseTransaction.java:235)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Jun 03, 2015 2:04:10 PM com.worklight.core.ilmt.WorklightILMTLogger dumpLicense
INFO: FWLSE0277I: Creating an ILMT record in the file '/var/ibm/common/slm/e1178f0cf1cfd7b4017f37827cae010b.slmtag'.
```

Comment: How big is your `.wlapp` file?

Comment: @AndrewFerrier less than 1mb

Comment: OK. I notice you mention Tomcat, but it also looks like you're using MFP 7.0. MFP has used WebSphere Liberty for some time, not Tomcat. Can you clarify?

Comment: Sorry, let me withdraw that last statement. I thought you were talking about the embedded MFP development server.

Comment: It does sound like the error is suggesting a fix though: "Switch to direct data transfer via JMX." Have you investigated that?

Comment: @AndrewFerrier Yes, production environment.

Comment: @Sam Is this question still unresolved? I see from newer questions by you that you have already deployed apps. If this is resolved, please either answer it or remove the question.

Comment: @IdanAdar yep,fixed, but I'm not not sure it 's a exactly common way to solve this kind of issue. I will write my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this issue was solved by setting

```
max_allowed_packet = 30M
```

and

```
binlog_format = mixed
```

in mysql's `my.cnf` file.

Comment: I am having the same issue but in eclipse studio. Is there a way to solve it like this?